# Language supported in Visual studio for C++ __cplusplus is showing as C++98

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to run C++11 in my project. I add the compiler flag `/std:c++11` to the compiler, but when I check the version and print it out, it shows as C++98. This is in Visual Studio 2019.

This is what I'm using to print the language, and it shows as C++98:

```cpp
if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17\n";
else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C++14\n";
else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11\n";
else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98\n";
else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";

std::cout << "C++ langauge supported = " << __cplusplus << "\n";
```

Comment: VS2019 only supports C++14 and higher: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019

Comment: But is C++14 backwards compatible with c++11? I'm trying to make a project to go through the main features of each new language version.

Comment: Also see the [`/Zc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=vs-2019) flag usage for `__cplusplus`

Comment: @ChrisMM when I added the flag /Zc:__cplusplus it changed the output to c++14.

Comment: You also have the MS specific `_MSVC_LANG`.

Comment: In conjunction with the /std flag, it was possible to change it to C++17. Thank you if you'd like to make an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @AdamHoward `But is C++14 backwards compatible with c++11?` I believe so, at least for the most part excluding the most "backwards" code such as something that relies `__cplusplus` being exactly 201103L.

Comment: @ChrisMM I was referring to yours as the correct answer. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`/Zc:__cplusplus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=vs-2019) is required to turn on proper versioning for the `__cplusplus` macro.

Note, however, that *The compiler does not support standards switches for C++98, C++03, or C++11.* So it will only work with `/std:c++14` and later.

As was mentioned by Ted Lyngmo, there's also the `_MSVC_LANG` marco (this does not require the above compiler flag):

> `_MSVC_LANG` Defined as an integer literal that specifies the C++ language standard targeted by the compiler. It's set only in code compiled as C++. The macro is the integer literal value 201402L by default, or when the `/std:c++14` compiler option is specified. The macro is set to 201703L if the `/std:c++17` compiler option is specified. It's set to a higher, unspecified value when the `/std:c++latest` option is specified. Otherwise, the macro is undefined.

See this Visual C++ [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/) for more background on this behavior and the  new switch.