# fatal error: "dbus-cxx requires at least C++17"

Tags: c++, cmake, dbus

I am trying to use dbus-cxx for a C++ project I am working on. My project requires IPC, and I am trying to use dbus-cxx to accomplish that. I cloned the repository, and I used cmake to generate the files for VS 2019. I am trying to get the `signal_emitter.cpp` and `signal_receiver.cpp` building on VS 2019, but it is not working.

I have added the necessary directories for my project in Additional Include Directories, so the header file includes are working.

The error is that dbus-cxx requires C++17.

Error message when I try to build both of my cpps:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Checking Build System
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: signal-emitter, Configuration: Release x64 ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: signal-receiver, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/wangjes/Documents/GitHub/dbus-cxx/examples/basics/signals/src/CMakeLists.txt
2>signal_emitter.cpp
2>C:\Users\wangjes\Documents\GitHub\dbus-cxx\dbus-cxx.h(23,1): fatal error C1189: #error:  "dbus-cxx requires at least C++17."
3>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/wangjes/Documents/GitHub/dbus-cxx/examples/basics/signals/src/CMakeLists.txt
2>Done building project "signal-emitter.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
3>signal_receiver.cpp
3>C:\Users\wangjes\Documents\GitHub\dbus-cxx\dbus-cxx.h(23,1): fatal error C1189: #error:  "dbus-cxx requires at least C++17."
3>Done building project "signal-receiver.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
4>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Release x64 ------
4>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 2 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

I right-click my project > Properties > Configuration Properties > General, and next to C++ Language Standard, ISO C++17 Standard (std::c++17) is selected. So, I know that it is indeed using C++17.

Does anyone have any insight or seen this error before? I am using C++17, so I am not really sure what is the actual issue.

Edit: I have seen this [suggested post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057156/language-supported-in-visual-studio-for-c-cplusplus-is-showing-as-c98) as being similar to my question. However, this question does not answer my question, which is why dbus-cxx is still giving me an error when my required VS version matches the requirements.

But, I used that question to help me determine exactly what version __cplusplus I am using in VS 2019. My __cplusplus value is 199711L. I have found the line that triggers this error to appear, which is in `dbus-cxx.h`.

```
/***************************************************************************
 *   Copyright (C) 2007,2009,2010 by Rick L. Vinyard, Jr.                  *
 *   rvinyard@cs.nmsu.edu                                                  *
 *                                                                         *
 *   This file is part of the dbus-cxx library.                            *
 *                                                                         *
 *   The dbus-cxx library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or *
 *   modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License           *
 *   version 3 as published by the Free Software Foundation.               *
 *                                                                         *
 *   The dbus-cxx library is distributed in the hope that it will be       *
 *   useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty   *
 *   of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU   *
 *   General Public License for more details.                              *
 *                                                                         *
 *   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License     *
 *   along with this software. If not see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  *
 ***************************************************************************/
#define STRING2(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STRING2(x)

#pragma message(STRING(__cplusplus))

 
#ifndef DBUSCXX_DBUS_H
#define DBUSCXX_DBUS_H

#if !(__cplusplus >= 201703L)
#error "dbus-cxx requires at least C++17."
#endif

#include <dbus-cxx/dbus-cxx-config.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/callmessage.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/connection.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/signal.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/dispatcher.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/enums.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/error.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/errormessage.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/interface.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/interfaceproxy.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/messageappenditerator.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/message.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/messageiterator.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/methodbase.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/methodproxybase.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/object.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/objectproxy.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/pendingcall.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/returnmessage.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/signalbase.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/signalmessage.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/signalproxy.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/signature.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/signatureiterator.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/utility.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/variant.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/filedescriptor.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/simplelogger_defs.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/standalonedispatcher.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/propertyproxy.h>
#include <dbus-cxx/property.h>

#endif
```

I added the three lines of code at the top, to find out what version of __cplusplus I am running.

Comment: I'm not sure if those numbers are portable, so using MSC instead of GCC may be the cause. In any case, check the upstream bugtracker and file a feature request for compiling with MSC if that isn't supported yet!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the correct compiler flags are set in order for it to compile.  As far as I am aware, you need to make sure that you have at least `/Zc:__cplusplus /std:c++17` set for MSVC.

The `/Zc:__cplusplus` compiler switch tells [MSVC to report the correct version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) for the `__cplusplus` macro when used with the `/std` level.