# __cplusplus apparently not set correctly in Visual Studio 2022 when building for C++17?

Tags: visual-c++

My code has the following test, to protect code that only works in C++11 or newer.

It is evaluating to 0 despite `cl` being invoked with `/std:c++17` .

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103
```

I am seeing this in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) on Windows 11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Language supported in Visual studio for C++ \_\_cplusplus is showing as C++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057156/language-supported-in-visual-studio-for-c-cplusplus-is-showing-as-c98)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the project in question, and set Properties-->C/C++-->Command Line-->Additional Options with `/Zc:__cplusplus`

My best guess is that they instituted this bizarre mis-feature to service a "bug report" that code that was testing for the original value with `==` was failing once they increased the version number.

There is more information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-170

Comment: You don't have to guess, right on the page you linked it says "Because a lot of existing code appears to depend on the value of this macro matching `199711L`, the compiler doesn't change the value of the macro unless you explicitly opt in"