# I tried to use __int16 instead of char16_t, the same outcome. I'm finding replacement for std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t in c++17/c++20

Tags: c++

I'm new in c++.

I have code：

std::wstring_convertstd::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t, char16_t> convert;

But i got error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::locale::id std::codecvt<char16_t,char,struct _Mbstatet>::id fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals .

How can I solve this? Sorry, it's confusing.

I found the following messages.

> std::codecvt template from  itself isn't deprecated. For UTF-8
> to UTF-16, there is still std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>
> specialization.
>
> However, since std::wstring_convert and std::wbuffer_convert are
> deprecated along with the standard conversion facets, there isn't any
> easy way to convert strings using the facets.

So, I should implement it myself.

How to overcome this? I have tried to use __int16 instead of char16_t, the same outcome.

I want to use the replacement for std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t in c++17/c++20.

I try the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <charconv>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Convert UTF-8 to UTF-16
    std::string utf8String = "Hello, UTF-8!";
    std::u16string utf16String;

    auto result = std::from_chars(utf8String.data(), utf8String.data() + utf8String.size(), utf16String.data(), utf16String.data() + utf16String.size(), std::chars_format::utf8);

    if (result.ec == std::errc()) {
        std::wcout << L"UTF-16: " << utf16String << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Conversion error." << std::endl;
    }

    // Convert UTF-16 to UTF-8
    utf16String = u"Hello, UTF-16!";
    utf8String.clear();
    utf8String.resize(utf16String.size() * 4); // UTF-8 can take up to 4 bytes per character

    result = std::to_chars(utf8String.data(), utf8String.data() + utf8String.size(), utf16String.data(), utf16String.data() + utf16String.size(), std::chars_format::utf8);

    if (result.ec == std::errc()) {
        std::cout << "UTF-8: " << utf8String << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Conversion error." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I got error :namespace std has no member `to_chars` , `from_chars` members.

```
   if (__cplusplus == 201703L) {
    std::cout << "C++17 is supported." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
     std::cout << "C++17 is not supported." << std::endl;
    }
     return 0;
```

I found my compiler doesn't fully support C++17 through the previous code.

I follow the steps of [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/install-c17-support?view=msvc-170#prerequisites).
My windows SDK is Windows 11 version.
[image]

But my compiler still doesn't fully support C++17. I also didn't find Set the Compile As property to Compile as C code (/TC) in the final steps.

update：

Tried setting up C++ Language Standard but no success.

[image]

[image]

Comment: *But my compiler still doesn't fully support C++17.*  Have you tried changing the **C++ Language Standard** to ISO C++17 Standard?

Comment: Regarding the use of `__int16`, please note that all symbols starting with one or two underscore are usually internal or compiler-specific symbols, and unless specified in the C++ specification should be avoided for portability. `__int16` is not specified, but `std::int16_t` is (it's really "optional", but I doubt you ever come across a system that doesn't have it).

Comment: Your screenshot shows the compiler is set to compike the code as C+14 code

Comment: also, I recommend using a Unicode library instead of straight C++ to handle this: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu/howtouseicu.html

Comment: Hi,@ NathanOliver. Thanks. I follow the steps in the documents [Install C11 and C17 support in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/install-c17-support?view=msvc-170#prerequisites) . And I saw my screenshot same as the documents. What else should i do ?

Comment: Hi,@Eljay. Thank you. I'm not yet. Is there any steps to do that? Or I need to find documentation steps to try.

Comment: @wpf C and C++ are different languages.  You need to set the C++ language standard to C++17.  See your screenshot where it has the C++ language standard.  You'll see it is set to C++14

Comment: @NathanOliver. THANKS. I'm trying to do that and will come back later。

Comment: @NathanOliver. I update C++ Language Standard but no success.

Comment: Where are you getting `chars_format::utf8` from? It doesn't exist and `from_chars` can't transcode between string encodings. The code just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @wpf You may also need to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367383/cplusplus-apparently-not-set-correctly-in-visual-studio-2022-when-building-for

Comment: @wpf it seems you've mixed up things *a bit*. Visual Studio 2022 supports even C++ 23 features. The document you link to is about C, not C++, a different language. C++ isn't just C with an extra compilation step. [codecvt isn't deprecated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt), no matter what a 6 year old comment says. `codecvt<char16_t, char8_t, std::mbstate_t>` is supported since C++ 20 Why are you trying to *downgrade* to C++ 17 anyway?

Comment: Hi,@Panagiotis Kanavos. I found the statement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42946556/17960080) .  I have code
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert; 
But i got error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::locale::id std::codecvt<char16_t,char,struct _Mbstatet>::id 
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals . How can I solve this?